# Select text using keyboard only

Tags: keyboard, text-selection

I know how to select text (in a view) using the touch screen.

Is it possible to do the same via keyboard only?

If possible, please provide a way to do this on the emulator (I need this for a programming task).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed, just hold down the Shift key and move the cursor with the dpad/trackbal/etc.

From the comments:

The center key in the D-Pad activates the two text-selection hands, which can be moved anywhere using the D-Pad directional keys. Then, pressing the D-Pad center key again, copies the selection to the clipboard.

Comment: @Romain Guy Thank you. I am trying to do that on the emulator, but the moment I click the SHIFT key (with the mouse), I receive the message "Text copied to clipboard". How do I move the D-Pad cursor (on the **emulator**) while the SHIFT key is down?

Comment: Use your computer's keyboard :)

Comment: @Romain Guy Thanks again. I tried that, too, but the my computer's SHIFT key isn't recognized by the emulator. What am I missing?

Comment: @Romain Guy Got it! I don't need to use the SHIFT key at all. :)  The center key in the D-Pad activates the two text-selection hands, which can be moved anywhere using the D-Pad directional keys. Then, pressing the D-Pad center key again, copies the selection to the clipboard. Thank you!!! :)

Comment: That last part should be in the answer :-)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse Easy for your to say. :) What's obvious to many, may not be so obvious to n00bs like me.

Comment: Which is exactly why it should be in the answer, so it will help others too ;-) @an00b